# Margins too wide using a5paper Koma-Script option

Tags: margins, koma-script, paper-size

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, DIV=classic, 12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,graphicx,xunicode,color,lettrine}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Rare}, Numbers=OldStyle]{ibarraReal}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

The problem is in the `a5paper` option, because I get the following

[image]

So, how can I fix the problem with margins?

Comment: Hm that is never 12 pt on a A5 paper. I think you are putting the A5 paper at the upper left corner of a bigger paper somehow.

Comment: This is A5 superimposed on A4; add `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` to the preamble, as `scrbook` doesn't inform `xdvipdfmx` about the paper size.

Comment: Just for what is worth: it's not really a minimal example, nor is it a complete example. (Also you could have mentioned you were using XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Marc I think the example is excellent. Thank you for your review. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply add the `pagesize` option:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, DIV=classic, 12pt, pagesize]{scrbook}
```

It's actually an option for `typearea`. If you set this option, the class sets PDF page dimensions if used with pdfLaTeX, and uses a DVI `\special` for the paper size if it runs in DVI mode.

It can be forced specifying the output driver, such as `pagesize=pdftex`, `pagesize=dvips`, or `pagesize=dvipdfmx`, however I recommend to use `auto` or no value, which means the same.

Comment: I swear I searched for the answer in Koma doc, but didn't find it :) Thank you!